# ¿Cómo cambiar el tamaño del texto de un TextView en Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, textview, font-size

Hola estoy desarrollando una App con layout donde tengo un TextView y dos botones uno para Aumentar y otro para Disminuir el tamaño del texto del TextView. En la programación de estos botones escribi:

```
public void onZoomout(View view) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetalle);
    txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, txt.getTextSize()-1);
}

public void onZoomin(View view) {
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetalle);
    txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, txt.getTextSize()+1);
    }
```

Pero con esto ambos botones me aumentan el texto pro no logro el efecto contrario. Si alguien sabe como lo puedo arreglar u otro metodo para lograr este resultado sería de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

creo tener la solucion a tu problema al menos a mi me funciono de esta forma:

primero que nada cree una variable int para contener el valor que se le asignara al tamaño del texto

```
private int ValorTexto = 0;
```

como siguiente paso daremos un tamaño estandar al iniciar nuestra Activity

```
        if (ValorTexto == 0){
            ValorTexto = 20;
            txt01.setTextSize(ValorTexto);
        }
```

Luego cree tres botones para cambiar el tamaño de nuestro texto

```
        btn01.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Aif (ValorTexto == 0){
                    ValorTexto = 20;
                }
                if (ValorTexto < 30){
                    ValorTexto = ValorTexto + 1;
                    txt01.setTextSize(ValorTexto);
                }
            }
        });

        btn02.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ValorTexto = 20;
                txt01.setTextSize(ValorTexto);
            }
        });

        btn03.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ValorTexto == 0){
                    ValorTexto = 20;
                }
                if (ValorTexto > 10){
                    ValorTexto = ValorTexto - 1;
                    txt01.setTextSize(ValorTexto);
                }
            }
        });
```

de este modo podremos aumentar, disminuir y ademas reestablecer el tamaño de nuestro texto.
Espero que pueda servir este ejemplo