# Aumentar tamaño del texto desde la aplicación

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Buenas tardas quisiera hacer unos botones para reducir y aumentar el tamaño de la fuente ¿Cómo podría realizarlo?

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia, ya que no sé está planteando una duda/problema **en específico.** Intenta ser más específico, lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Encontré la solución en este post :  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153598/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-el-tama%C3%B1o-del-texto-de-un-textview-en-android-studio